# Query to search dates from angular to mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, datatable

I'm using angular datatables (server-side), I have a record of dates such as created on, date of birth, etc. In frontend, I'm showing dates as DD/MM/YYYY but in the backend, it is stored as YYYY-MM-DD. Since I'm having a search button so we the user type date as 26/02/2020, no records are returned. I want to write a query such that when a user types 26 only, his records with correspondance to dates should be returned. Can anybody help, please?